# batch script commands not working remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net, remote-debugging

I have a site that using asp.net and I am trying to create a batch script and run it.

I am using it to get latest files for a tfs workspace

the .bat only has

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

tf get "workspacePath" /force /recursive
```

when I run this on the remote server by clicking on the .bat itself, it works fine and does everything I need it to do.

When I try to use this through the site it does not work.

I confirmed it does read and attempt to execute the script by adding a random .txt file in the location of the bat and have the script delete it, which worked through the site.

I have many times run batch scripts through my site, but for this specific example it is not working.

I have tried executing it via...

```
Process.Start(@"filepath\getStuff.bat");
```

I have also tried just bypassing the batch script by using psExec

```
Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"path\PsExec.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\vdvws052 ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"" get ""workspacePath"" /force /recursive";
    p.Start();
```

With each way I have tried I have also added a `.WaitForExit()` incase that was the issue, but that didn't help either

Comment: Make sure you specify the `StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` also see if you can execute `PsExec` from remote computer's command prompt. See if you get any error returned from `PsTools`.

Comment: I do not know why you have the double quotes inside of the `Arguments=` part.. why don't you take advantage of the string.Format function and do something like this 
`p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", SomePath, someotherparams)`....etc and add `{}` params for the number of params you will be passing

Comment: @MethodMan When the string is @"some text" escape characters are ignored and \" is the same as "" in order to represent a one single quote

Comment: I know the use of `@` and escape characters.. you couldn't have this issue if you were to pass in arguments using the string.Format.. perhaps you should give it a try..

Answer (score 0):

Use the & sign for each command.

&   Used to combine two commands (or more). Executes command1 and then command2

```
""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"" & get ""workspacePath"" /force /recursive"
```

&&  A conditional combination. Executes command2 if command1 completes successfully

```
""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"" && get ""workspacePath"" /force /recursive"
```